# TimeOut Exception in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm running into a problem when modifying a WCF service.

The original service method looks like this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
void Login(string userName, string password);
```

This method works.

The problem is that when I change it to this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
bool Login(string userName, string password);
```

It stops working and times out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does tracing on the service show any exceptions? I've run into problems where a client will time out after running into some type of contract based issue within the service.

Comment: Now that you mention it, there is an exception on the server in the System.ServiceModel.dll. I'll have to drill down and see what's causing the exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying the web service did you update the client proxy ([svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx))?

Comment: I was curious of the same thing.  If you don't update your client you will definitely have issues.